# Return sub-set of records that don't exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query that returns me the whole set:

```
SELECT s.id, s.status, s.created_at
FROM scores s
WHERE s.account_id IN (
  SELECT a.id
  FROM accounts a
  WHERE a.status = 'ACTIVE' AND a.created_at >= DATE(NOW()) - 3 AND a.tool = 'GLR'
) ORDER BY s.created_at ASC;
```

...but now I want a sub-set of that: all the records in `account` that doesn't have any record in `score`.

---

I've tried these, but no luck so far O:)

```
--- Using LEFT JOIN
SELECT s.account_id, s.status, s.created_at
FROM scores s
  LEFT JOIN accounts a ON s.account_id = a.id
    AND a.status = 'ACTIVE'
    AND a.created_at >= DATE(NOW()) - 3
    AND a.tool = 'GLR'
WHERE s.account_id IS NULL ORDER BY s.created_at ASC;

--- Using EXISTS / NOT EXISTS
SELECT s.account_id, s.status, s.created_at
FROM scores s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM accounts a
  WHERE s.account_id = a.id
    AND a.status = 'ACTIVE'
    AND a.created_at >= DATE(NOW()) - 3
    AND a.tool = 'GLR'
) ORDER BY s.created_at ASC;
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the order? Your starting point is `accounts` so that should be the table you return first and then use `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS` on `scores` table

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN scores s ON s.account_id = a.id
WHERE a.status = 'ACTIVE' AND a.created_at >= DATE(NOW()) - 3 AND a.tool = 'GLR'
  AND s.account_id IS NULL
```